# how to use emacsclient -e "command" to convert a .org file to html?

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode, emacsclient

I want use `emacsclient -e "command"` to covert org mode file to html file, such as:

```
emacsclient -e "(org-html-export-as-html ./mynote.org)" > ./mynote.html
```

hope it will be save output to mynote.html file.
But I'm not familiar with elisp yet. Actually, `org-html-export-as-html` has many parameter I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A/ You can do it "yourself" with:**

```
emacsclient -e "(progn (find-file \"file.org\") (org-html-export-to-html) (kill-buffer))"
```

**Caveat:** to make it works you should have started Emacs with

```
emacs --daemon
```

or if you already have an Emacs running, type `M-x server-start`

**B/ use a github package**

https://github.com/nhoffman/org-export

which creates some compiled lisp executables:

- org-export html
- org-export tangle
- ...

However my personnal experience is that the command line approach is faster.

**C/ Bonus, tangling file**

You can tangle files with the same command line approach:

```
emacsclient -e "(org-babel-tangle-file \"file.org\")"
```

---

**Update, gives more details about C/**

"tangling" is a term coined from [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming)

> Literate programming (LP) tools are used to obtain two representations
>   from a literate source file: one suitable for further compilation or
>   execution by a computer, the "tangled" code, and another for viewing
>   as formatted documentation, which is said to be "woven" from the
>   literate source.[3] While the first generation of literate programming
>   tools were computer language-specific, the later ones are
>   language-agnostic and exist above the programming languages.

You have a unique file:

```
#+TITLE: My Org file

* Configuration

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :tangle yes :tangle "tangled.sh" :shebang "#!/bin/bash"
echo "This is my configuration script"
echo "..do something interesting here.."
#+END_SRC
```

You can html export it (parts A/ or B/), but but can also export the code it contains, here a shell script. From Emacs this can be done with `C-c C-v t` or, from shell, using the command I provided in **C/** part. The result is the automatic generation of the `tangled.sh` file.

You can have a look here: [Babel: active code in Org-mode](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/index.html) for further details.

Comment: A works great for me! B seems great to but I'm not test yet. C print nil without nothing. Can you give me some explain of C? Document say the method  `Extract the bodies of source code blocks in FILE.` I don't know what's the means

Comment: Hi, can I set body-only when export html file, such as: `emacsclient -e "(progn (setq body-only 1) (find-file \"docker.org\") (org-html-export-to-html) (kill-buffer))"`. I give attempt but it not affect at all.

Comment: I finally find &optional usage in elisp. Outputting only body could be deal with `emacsclient -e "(progn (find-file \"file.org\") (org-html-export-to-html nil nil nil 1 nil) (kill-buffer))"` is ok.  ;-)

Comment: I have detailed the C part (see Update)

Comment: I always use the "command line" approach (A/ and C/). In the past, I have tested B/ but the commands were significantly slower than a direct emacs server + shell command line approach. Maybe this is no longer the case now, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, correct way should be

```
emacsclient -e "(org-html-publish-to-html '()  \"file.org\" \".\")"
```

But it complains about `*ERROR*: ‘org-publish-cache-get’ called, but no cache present` - for me it looks like a bug in Org-mode

Comment: If you want to export you should use an export function; if you want to publish you should use a publish function. But publishing requires more setup than export does.

Comment: @Nick - yes, my bad - you're correct... But to use export functions more setup also necessary...

Comment: Not really: see the other answer. You open the file and you export it.